# How do you separate a character array into two separate arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm just learning about character arrays.
From what I understand, in C++ character arrays store a space as NULL. Is there a way I can use that to separate an array into two?

```
    char Full_Name[14] = {Henry Ford};

  /*how would I go about separating that into two character arrays? I have 
    an idea more or less, but surely there's something simple that I haven't 
    learned yet. */

    char First_Name[7], Last_Name[7];

    strcpy(First_Name, )
    strcpy(Last_Name, )
```

Comment: Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) with the `>>` input operator.

Comment: And please [get a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), because there are some very basic misunderstandings you have.

Comment: _character arrays store a space as NULL_ no, they store space as space.

Comment: strcpy and char arrays are used in C. Don't do that in C++, use std::string.

Comment: It's for a class assignment. We're supposed to ask user for full name and input that into a char array  char Full[40], and parse it into two other arrays char First[20], char Last[20].  I'm looking online for solutions. The hint on the instruction was to use strcpy(First, "xx") strcpy(Last, "yy").  From what I've been searching, looks like I can probably accomplish what I'm trying to do by using strtok().                                                                    Is this website not for students or something? Some of you guys seem upset at my question.